# Using content search web part to build a site navigation (SP 2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, content-search-web-part, cswp

Problem: I've got a site with 15 subsites, each which in turn has many pages. I want to use a content search web part to query all sub sites, and display each sub site as a heading, with the three most visited pages linked in bullet points under each heading. I want to make this into a template that can be applied to around 50 other sites. Each other site has different content, but I want the same logic applied - so that's why I want to use content search rather than building the content statically. In essence, what I am looking to build is a type of navigation built with the CSWP.

Question: I am not super adept at SP technically speaking, so sorry if my questions are a bit stupid. but I've got people who could help me out if I could formulate the problem a little better, and get a better understanding of which nuts and bolts that needs to be taken into consideration.

- First of all, is the Content Search Web Part suitable for this task?
- Is it possible to query the sub sites and the pages belonging to each sub site, group the results by sub site and order the results by page
  views?
- Another problem is that it needs to look nice enough. Could the
  results be shown in a table with three columns, five sub sites in
  each column?

Comment: How are you judging between the most visited page in a sub site? Do you already have a logic in place?

Comment: Hi Asad! I was hoping that I could rely on sorting the results based on one of the OOTB ranking models. But this is where my knowledge gets blurry - in the CSWP query properties, when you go to advanced options, you can add levels of sorting > rank > and pick a ranking model. I was hoping I could for example choose Popularity Model. Would this work? Ideally it would be based on traffic from SP metrics.

Comment: Hi Bearman, were you able to solve this?